# Organization detail shows API Requests, Last 24 Hours 298 (5,000 max). What are the variables contributing to the API requests?

Tags: api, governorlimits

When i check the Organization detail for the API usage for the day, it shows API Requests, Last 24 Hours 298 (5,000 max).

According to my knowledge i did not made any API request. But i worked in some coding in Eclipse IDE. Does it count to API request?

Apart from that i am making a callout (consuming SAP webservices) to SAP. Does it count to API request?

I am totally confused what are variables contributing to 298 API requests? Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Eclipse IDE will consume API calls every time you save or refresh a file; and it's not just one API call per action necessarily, authentication/handshakes consume API calls as well, so saving one change to a file can consume two (or, somehow, sometimes, more) API calls.

In the Winter 14 release, the Developer Console consumes a LOT of API Calls, as it polls for logs and updates the whole time it is open. Leaving the Developer console open in the background will slowly eat up API calls, and we've had two instances in our office of someone working with the Developer Console for a few hours and completely finishing off their 5,000 limit in a DE.

In fact, if you note the number of API calls made, open the Developer Console, wait a minute, maybe open, edit and save a file - you can probably note somewhere in the region of 17 - 20 API calls made.

External tools (such as the Eclipse IDE) record a "login" under the User Detail Page - with an application name telling you what program it was logging in, and you can be fairy sure then that this application will be consuming API calls.

[image: login history]

You can also set alert messages if you have a live system which is dependant on the API limit not being breached that will send out messages (at an interval you can set) when it passes certain thresholds.

[image: api usage]

Comment: Thanks Simon. i understood now. i am little bit hesitate to accept why salesforce consider the activities in dev console to add to the limit. I accept with Eclipse.

Comment: I agree, it sucks. Try using dev console in a DE orge with 500 requests max when you are debugging and writing code, etc. Major limitation. But, take a de org, look at company information, check API requests. Then open dev console and perform a few tasks. It is an API hog and should not be counted but it is. It uses the API just like any other tool, only it is essentially useless.

Comment: It totally sucks. in Spring 14 the developer console consumes a LOT less API calls, because I think a lot of the monitoring has been moved over to use the newer streaming API. You have to remember that the Developer Console is in essence a heavyweight javascript IDE, so most of its work is done via Apex Remoting - for an improved USER experience, which means consuming API calls back to the servers.. it's the best technical solution. Why Salesforce don't "cleverly" disregard these as contributing towards your API limit to encourage it's uptake is a completely different debate!!

Answer (score 2):

API requests are anything that access your salesforce instance via the API. IDE counts, developer console counts, any integrations connecting TO your instance count. Calling out FROM your instance does not count.

Comment: Thanks, Eric. i can accept IDE counts, integration counts but why the developer console? it is still inside the salesforce sharing the same session?